# Pulling objects from a collection that satisfies a condition

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I was wondering whether you know using LINQ in C# to pull a list of objects from a collection that satisfies a condition?

I am trying to pull a list of `Person` objects from a list whose IDs match in an integer list. Please see the code below (I am trying to pull all person objects whose IDs are in the integer list).

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

...

var intList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var perList = new List<Person>
{
    new Person {Id = 1, FirstName = "Thomas", LastName = "Joseph"},
    new Person {Id = 2, FirstName = "Joseph", LastName = "Austin"},
    new Person {Id = 3, FirstName = "Lee", LastName = "Hentry"},
    new Person {Id = 4, FirstName = "Abraham", LastName = "Tony"}
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) methods:

```
var people = perList
    .Where(person => intList.Contains(person.Id))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) methods:

```
var filteredPeople = perList.Where(person => intList.Any(person.Id)).ToList();
```